# Close a split window in Vim without resizing other windows

Tags: vim, window, split

If I have a Vim window open with 2 splits in it (3 total buffers visible) and I've adjusted the viewport of each split, then I close one buffer, the other two buffer's viewport's are automatically resized.

Is there a way to maintain or at least better scale the split when I close a buffer?

```
1) Vim window with three splits, custom size:
  +---+-------+---+
  |   |       |   |
  | 1 |   2   | 3 |
  |   |       |   |
  +---+-------+---+
2) Close buffer 3, splits are resized to "best fit":
  +-------+-------+
  |       |       |
  |   1   |   2   |
  |       |       |
  +-------+-------+
3) I want it to stay like this, resize only adjacent buffer:
  +---+-----------+
  |   |           |
  | 1 |     2     |
  |   |           |
  +---+-----------+
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
set noea
```

In other words:

```
set noequalalways
```

See [equalalways](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'equalalways') in the Vim documentation.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I did search the documentation but I guess I didn't search hard enough :-/

Comment: vim's documentation is fantastic as long as you know what you're looking for.  Figuring out what you should be looking for is a bit trickier.

Comment: Shouldn't the second line read `set noequalalways`?  (This confused me at first.)  (+1, btw)

Comment: Yes it should. @strager could you edit your answer ?

Comment: This was way too hard to find! 